# Python - determining the frequency of a string and further processing

Tags: python, arrays, text-processing

I have some text files containing variable column numbers, delimited by `\t` (tab). Something like this:

```
value1x1 . . . . . . value1xn
   .     . . . . . . value2xn
   .     . . . . . .     .
valuemx1 . . . . . . valuemxn
```

I can scan through and determine the frequency of value's with the following code ;

```
f2 = open("out_freq.txt", 'w')
f = open("input_raw",'r')
whole_content = (f.read())
list_content = whole_content.split()
dict = {}
for one_word in list_content:
    dict[one_word] = 0
for one_word in list_content:
    dict[one_word] += 1
a = str(sorted(dict.items(),key=func))
f2.write(a)
f2.close()
```

and output of this is as following:

```
('26047', 13), ('42810', 13), ('61080', 13), ('106395', 13), ('102395', 13)...
```

Syntax of this is `('value', occurence_number)` and it works as expected. What I am trying to achieve is:

1. To transform the output as following syntax: `('value', occurrence_number, column_number)` where column number is the column number that this value occurred in the input_raw.txt
2. To group values with same occurrence numbers to separate columns and write these to a different file

Comment: What about `collections.Counter`?

Comment: If you want to keep track of information about the column *why* aren't you reading the file line by line or at least processing the content line by line? Also, what happens if the same key appear more than one time in different columns?

Comment: for line in "input_raw"
    if  search_string in line:
I used this expression for reading line-by-line but it quits scanning the current line if search_string is found. For cases like same search_string is found in input_raw at different columns, this doesn't work.

Comment: @y33t I can't understand your comment. There is no "search_string" in your code... I don't understand what you mean in point 2. How should the values be separated in different files? Try to write an example of input and the expected output.

Comment: @Bakuriu search_string is the string I want to search, doesn't matter what it is. assume search_string="ok".

Comment: It is still unclear what happens if the same value occurs in different columns on the same or different lines? What is the desired output (after grouping the values)? [Take a look at the example that collects column numbers in a list for each value](http://ideone.com/Lxp76k)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you want something like the following:

```
import itertools as it
from collections import Counter

with open("input_raw",'r') as fin, open("out_freq.txt", 'w') as fout:
    counts = Counter(it.chain.from_iterable(enumerate(line.split())
                                                  for line in fin))
    sorted_items = sorted(counts.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
    a = ', '.join(str((int(key[1]), val, key[0])) for key, val in sorted_items))
    fout.write(a)
```

Note that this code uses a tuple as key, to distinguish between equal values if they appear in different columns. From your question is not clear if this is possible and what should be done in this case.

Example usage:

```
>>> import itertools as it
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> def get_sorted_items(fileobj):
...     counts = Counter(it.chain.from_iterable(enumerate(line.split()) for line in fileobj))
...     return sorted(counts.items(), key=lambda x:x[1], reverse=True)
... 
>>> data = """
... 10 11 12 13 14
... 10 9  7  6  4
... 9  8  12 13 0
... 10 21 33 6  1
... 9  9  7  13 14
... 1  21 7  13 0
... """
>>> with open('input.txt', 'wt') as fin:  #write data to the input file
...     fin.write(data)
... 
>>> with open('input.txt', 'rt') as fin:
...     print ', '.join(str((int(key[1]), val, key[0])) for key, val in get_sorted_items(fin))
... 
(13, 4, 3), (10, 3, 0), (7, 3, 2), (14, 2, 4), (6, 2, 3), (9, 2, 0), (0, 2, 4), (9, 2, 1), (21, 2, 1), (12, 2, 2), (8, 1, 1), (1, 1, 4), (1, 1, 0), (33, 1, 2), (4, 1, 4), (11, 1, 1)
```

Comment: I got     a = ', '.join(str((key[1], val, key[0])) for key, val in sorted_items) TypeError: 'enumerate' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Comment: @y33t I forgot to transform it in a tuple. Now it should work.

Comment: @JonClements Yep. Due to copy past from OP code. I renamed the variables and didn't think of removing it.

Comment: @Bakuriu NameError: name 'func' is not defined, interesting.

Comment: @y33t I deliberately left the name `func`, which is what you wrote in *your* code, since you stated that the code was working, use the same function. If you want to sort the values so that the first elements are those that appeared more times use `key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True`. Regarding writing the values in different files you didn't explain the criteria so I can't help you there.

Comment: your code counts the identical lines in the file. You probably mean: [`Counter((value, column) for line in fin for column, value in enumerate(line.split()))`](http://ideone.com/Lxp76k) instead.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian Ouch, in the first revision I used `update`, which did what I wanted, but I messed up when making the genexp. I prefer using `itertools.chain` instead of nesting the genexp.